# Standardizing file names in a folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any function to standardize file names in a folder?

I'm developing a program in C # that needs to check if the filenames are spelled correctly and then move them to another folder.

For example I usually get a file like this **082018 - Name - Reason.txt**, however some people forget to put the spacing or invert the values, I need to check the names and put them in the pattern above.

Comment: Unfortunately not -- you will have to add that functionality into your program. You will have to write something that can validate the file names (maybe regular expressions or a custom parsing function), break the three components of the title apart and rearrange them with the right spacing and order.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! At Least I have a direction now.

Answer (score 3):

I think using a `Regex` for this situation would be ideal. You can write a simple function that would verify if the file name is in order, and even return each part of it.

Let's declare a `class` to hold your file name data in the following format.

```
public class FileNameFormat
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}
```

Now a method like this would verify your file name, using the `Regex` provided.

```
public static FileNameFormat VerifyFileName(string fileName)
{
    var fileNameInfo = new FileNameFormat();
    fileNameInfo.FileName = fileName;

    var rgx = new Regex(@"^(\d{6}) - (.+) - (.+).txt$");
    var match = rgx.Match(fileName);
    fileNameInfo.IsValid = match.Success;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(match.Groups[1].Value, "MMddyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime result))
    {
        fileNameInfo.Date = result;
    }
    fileNameInfo.Name = match.Groups[2].Value;
    fileNameInfo.Reason = match.Groups[3].Value;

    return fileNameInfo;
}
```

The `Regex` assumes:

- Date in your file name is of length 6, and are all numerical values.
- All file names have the extension `.txt`.
- Both `Name` and `Reason` sections are at least 1-character long.

Also, in the case that the `Match` is a success, even though I convert the value to a `DateTime` I'm not doing any additional verifications to see if it's in that format. For example, if the date is set in the format `yyMMdd` the `Regex` would still pass, but may not be the format you want (assuming the format you're using is `MMddyy`).

So this is really only a starting point but you can change your `Regex` and verifications based on your needs/constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I think this will work. I will try this as soon as i get in home.

Comment: Sach, I am new in development and i forgot to say that i need to do a console application, This method could be used in this format ?

Comment: Yes as you can see it doesn't use any UI elements.

Comment: Sorry for asking again but i am having a issue with a "{" my code is like that: public class FileNameFormat
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {  < == showing error " } expected" but i checked and all the { are closed.

        public string FileName;
        public DateTime Date;
        public string Name;
        public string Reason;
        public bool IsValid;

        FileNameFormat VerifyFileName(string fileName)
        {
            var fileNameInfo = new FileNameFormat();
            fileNameInfo.FileName = fileName;